# Error with running rake commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

While working with old app using rails 2.0.2 with ruby 1.8.6, getting following problem...

when I try to execute any rake(v 0.8.3) command { eg. rake routes}.

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'routes'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@rails202/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1706:in `[]'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@rails202/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:2018:in `invoke_task'
 ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@rails202/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1997:in `top_level'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@rails202/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1997:in `each'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@rails202/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1997:in `top_level'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@rails202/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:2036:in `standard_exception_handling'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@rails202/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1991:in `top_level'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@rails202/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1970:in `run'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@rails202/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:2036:in `standard_excetion_handling'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@rails202/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1967:in `run'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@rails202/bin/rake:31
```

Initially there was no rakefile, I added one with following contents

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rake'

XXX::Application.load_tasks
```

Comment: I can't believe that this works in a Rails 2 app, since there should be no `config/application.rb` and no `XXX::Application`.
So, check the answer by PriteshJ and use his Rails 2 rake file. Also make sure to call the file `Rakefile` and not `rakefile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a rails 2.3.8 app

The Rakefile looks like this:

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.
require 'thread'
require(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'boot'))

require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rake/rdoctask'

require 'tasks/rails'
```

The rake file you have added is rails 3 compatible ,I do not think it works for earlier version.

EDIT: You must be having the setup for rails 2.0.2 already , i would recommend to create a new  rails 2.0.2 app and identify the missing links.

Comment: Thanks @PriteshJ and severin, I tried with this Rakefile, but it is showing the same error again even with rake -v. But rake works well with custom rake tasks like following

         desc "This is a simple test task"
 
         task :doit do
         puts "DONE"
         end

Comment: @Sush, have to tried creating a new rails 2.0.2 application?, check and compare the missing links is what i can recommend.

Comment: Thanks again @PritheshJ, I think it's really a very good idea :)

Comment: Need your help again @PriteshJ, actually where should I start looking the differences. It's really a very big app.

Comment: you should look mainly in the config folder and the config files in the main dir like Rakefile  and others if any.

Comment: Thanks again you all, I made silliest mistake. I just named Rakefile wrongly to RakeFile and rake wasn't able to find it. Thanks again PriteshJ and @severin for your valuable time.